# Spring data jpa stopping thread on query?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jpa

On findAll,save,delete, etc -- thread stopping.
Tomcats log shows 2 schema updates. Why ?
And WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (default) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'

Database is clear. Please, help me!!
This is my confing:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("depended")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository")
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/welcome").setViewName("welcome");
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stakes");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("1234");
        return dataSource;
    }

/*    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Response.class);
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return factoryBean;
    }*/

    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql","true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");

        return properties;
    }




    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("model");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }




}
```

This is my repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ResponseRepository
        extends CrudRepository<Response,Integer> {



        public List<Response> findByHost(String host,Sort sort);

}
```

Tomcat say:

```
июл 20, 2015 3:06:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
июл 20, 2015 3:06:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
июл 20, 2015 3:06:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
июл 20, 2015 3:06:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
июл 20, 2015 3:06:48 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:48 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
июл 20, 2015 3:06:48 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
июл 20, 2015 3:06:48 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
июл 20, 2015 3:06:48 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
июл 20, 2015 3:06:48 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
июл 20, 2015 3:06:48 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: stakes.parseddata
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [data, response_id]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_pcga95gtu9m7brdlkmgjegmpa]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_pcga95gtu9m7brdlkmgjegmpa]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: stakes.resp
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [lastposthref, host, id, time]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:49 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: stakes.parseddata
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [data, response_id]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_pcga95gtu9m7brdlkmgjegmpa]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_pcga95gtu9m7brdlkmgjegmpa]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: stakes.resp
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [lastposthref, host, id, time]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry addEntityManagerFactory
WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (default) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
июл 20, 2015 3:06:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Comment: While I empathize with your despair, you cannot be helped based on the provided information.

Comment: For me it is unclear what you are asking. One thing though is that your configuration is loaded twice and basically all your beans are duplicated. Don't load the same configuration in the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`. When component scanning make sure you don't scan the same package twice.